# What is a Polynomial defined as $p=d/dt$?

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, laplace-transform, control-theory

I'm solving a problem related with Laplace Transformation and and Transfer Function for a Linear systems Class, but I found a definition that is not clear to me. This is the full problem:

Consider a 2 input-2 output system denoted by:

> $D_{11}(p)y_{1}(t)+D_{12}(p)y_{2}(t)=N_{11}(p)u_{1}(t)+N_{12}(p)u_{2}(t)$
>
> $D_{21}(p)y_{1}(t)+D_{22}(p)y_{2}(t)=N_{21}(p)u_{1}(t)+N_{22}(p)u_{2}(t)$

where $N_{ij}$ and $D_{ij}$ are polynomials of $p=d/dt$. Whats the Transfer Matrix of the system?

So, my question is What does the polynomial $p=d/dt$ mean?

My approach for solving this is multiply $y(s)=D^{-1}(s)*N(s)*u(s)=G(s)u(s)$, but still no idea about the sense of $p$.

Comment: The "multiplication" operation here is composition, so that $p^2=\frac{d^2}{dt^2}$.

Comment: I guess its defined by the letter $p$ the differential operator $d/dt$. Then if the $N_{i,j}$ and the $D_{i,j}$ are polynomials then $N_{i,j}(p)$ and $D_{i,j}(p)$ are differential operators, by example if $D_{1,2}:=X^2-3X+1$ then $D_{1,2}(p)=\frac{d^2}{dt^2}-3\frac{d}{dt}+I$ where $I$ is the identity map, hence $D_{1,2}(p) f(t)=f''(t)-3f'(t)+f(t)$ for some twice differentiable function $f$

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering if you know of some books where I cold study topics such as Function analysis, fundamentals of linear algebra and differential equations, and stuff related with control systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably what is meant is polynomial functions of $\dfrac d{dt}.$

For example, suppose $f(x)=x^3-5x^2 + 2x +9.$

Then $f\left( \dfrac d {dt} \right) = \dfrac {d^3} {dt^3} - 5 \dfrac{d^2}{dt^2} + 2 \dfrac d {dt} + 9,$ so that, for example,
$$
f\left( \frac d{dt} \right) u(t) = u'''(t) - 5u''(t) + 2u'(t) + 9u(t).
$$